# Django urls page not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

In my urls.py I include my urls for each app, for example;

```
from app.insight import urls as insight_urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('insight/', include(insight_urls), name='insight')
]
```

In insight.urls I include the view and the url like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', InsightAddView.as_view(), name='create-insight')
]
```

The error I get says:
`Page not found. No insight found matching the query`

However, when I change the `create-insight` url from `create/` to `create/new/` it works. 
Why doesn't the `create/` url work?

Comment: Can you show the complete URL that you've tried?

Comment: Is it possible that you use the same ```create/``` url pattern in anywhere else in your project?

Comment: @cagrias I do, but always through another app include so therefore the url is different I would say...

Comment: Can you please share these two ```url.py```s and your main ```urls.py```?

Comment: I found out the problem. Thank you @cagrias. I had another url inside insight.urls matching the create/ url.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cagrias I solved the problem. I had another url matching the `create/` url. This one:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', InsightView.as_view(), name='read-insight-slug')
```

I solved it by changing that one to:

```
path('read/<slug:slug>/', InsightView.as_view(), name='read-insight-slug'),
```